# OpenSC fails to connect javacard with PKCS applet

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, javacard, openpgp

I have empty [JavaCOS A40](https://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/id~711/javacos-a40-dual-interface-java-card-64k/p/index.shtml) smartcard and want make it a PKCS PKI card.

I'm going to use it as ssh key and for e-contracts signing. Russia don't provide smartcard-based e-id for citizens like EU countries do. Commercial e-signature providers are selling some sort of password-protected usb drives, that's unsafe to use, because you can easily export private key. Also they sell normal smartcards, but they are really expensive(x10-x20 than empty javacard) and short-living(about 1 year). So i want to make my own PKI card based on RSA algorhitms from javacard.

Now my javacard is in state `OP_READY` and I don't changed it, because changes are irreversible. It use default key and anyone can upload anything. I use `ACR38U` reader with `pcsc` linux driver on `Ubuntu` and it works as expected, so I used [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) to upload PKI [IsoApplet](https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet) as default. So GP's output:

```
java -jar gp.jar -list
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
ISD: A000000003000000 (OP_READY)
     Privs:   SecurityDomain, CardLock, CardTerminate, CardReset, CVMManagement

APP: F276A288BCFBA69D34F31001 (SELECTABLE)
     Privs:   CardReset

PKG: F276A288BCFBA69D34F310 (LOADED)
     Version: 1.0
     Applet:  F276A288BCFBA69D34F31001
```

`cardpeek` successfully connects to it and I can send low-level commands to applet
[image: cardpeek]

But when I try to connect to card and applet using `opensc` prober to see Answer-To-Request(ATR), it fails `opensc-tool --reader 0 --atr`. [See maximum debug info](https://gist.github.com/cyclopentan/67c7930bc6cb2d3962d3600b4859b5f6)

Shortened version:

```
opensc-tool --reader 0 --atr -vv
Connecting to card in reader ACS ACR 38U-CCID 00 00...
0x7fc849e7e740 22:17:14.634 [opensc-tool] card.c:200:sc_connect_card: called
0x7fc849e7e740 22:17:14.634 [opensc-tool] card-entersafe.c:138:entersafe_match_card: called
Failed to connect to card: Card command failed
0x7fc849e7e740 22:17:14.797 [opensc-tool] ctx.c:870:sc_release_context: called
```

According to manufacturer info, card is supporting `T=0` over ISO7816, but opensc tries to communicate with `T=1`. So how I can fix this?

Seems, that opensc tools are not customizable. I need to use `pkcs15-crypt`, but it can't connect. May I change drivers, recompile opensc with patches, or use another utility? How another ways I can use to work with OpenPGP for example?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is certainly not with the transport protocol because it communicates an APDU with the card. When looking at the logging it seems to incorrectly guess from the ATR that the card is an `epass2003`:

```
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.904 [opensc-tool] card.c:287:sc_connect_card: matched: epass2003
```

then execute a command to it:

```
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.904 [opensc-tool] apdu.c:378:sc_single_transmit: CLA:0, INS:CA, P1:1, P2:86, data(0) (nil)
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.904 [opensc-tool] reader-pcsc.c:283:pcsc_transmit: reader 'ACS ACR 38U-CCID 00 00'
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.904 [opensc-tool] reader-pcsc.c:284:pcsc_transmit: 
Outgoing APDU (5 bytes):
00 CA 01 86 00 .....
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.904 [opensc-tool] reader-pcsc.c:212:pcsc_internal_transmit: called
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.912 [opensc-tool] reader-pcsc.c:293:pcsc_transmit: 
Incoming APDU (2 bytes):
6D 00 m.
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.912 [opensc-tool] apdu.c:390:sc_single_transmit: returning with: 0 (Success)
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.912 [opensc-tool] apdu.c:543:sc_transmit: returning with: 0 (Success)
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.912 [opensc-tool] card.c:459:sc_unlock: called
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.912 [opensc-tool] reader-pcsc.c:662:pcsc_unlock: called
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.921 [opensc-tool] card-epass2003.c:189:epass2003_check_sw: Instruction code not supported or invalid
0x7f175a21e740 22:14:13.921 [opensc-tool] card-epass2003.c:1118:get_data: get_data failed: -1204 (Unsupported INS byte in APDU)
```

Now this command is executed over the communication channel in T=1 (it's very unlikely that the card just supports T=0 if it also supports T=CL, because T=CL and T=1 are very much alike - at the higher level). Not only that, it correctly returns a result, even if that is *higher level* error condition: 6D00 meaning instruction not supported.

This leads to the high lever error condition:

```
Failed to connect to card: Card command failed
```

which is slightly misleading, because it certainly *connected* to the card, it just wasn't able to get any data from it using a GET DATA command. This isn't that strange because it didn't first select any applet and GET DATA (with INS-truction `CA`) is not likely to be present in the root folder / applet.

TL;DR your connection is fine, now start programming it by issuing GlobalPlatform card manager commands to it. If possible use a different tool or get opensc tools to skip the identification phase / initial commands to it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but the mods forgot to include the right tags so I didn't see it.

Comment: I wish I had. I have posted this because the issue was clearly not with the transport protocol. However, the card clearly doesn't implement the protocol that the tool expects - GET DATA in the root doesn't have to be implemented for Java Card, and I don't know how to suppress the protocol. If I find some time I might check tomorrow. As last resort you could have a look at the source code and possibly disable the matched ATR. Or contact the devs of the tool and ask them to do it.

Answer (score 1):

IsoApplet and OpenPGP are two different world. For OpenPGP support, look at either SmartPGP by ANSSI-FR on github or ykneo-openpgp (also on Github).

For signatures, you also do not need pkcs15-crypt but should work via PKCS#11 library instead.

For this specific reason - the card being matched as epass, disable the epass driver in opensc.conf.

Comment: I'm new to javacard. Glad to see you here. Thank you for GP, it's great tool